# Migrating from Gruntfile.js to gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp

I am trying to use the tool [grunt2gulp.js](https://github.com/omouse/grunt2gulp.js) to migrate multiple projects that were set up with grunt into gulp. However, I am unsure how to proceed.

The tool grunt2gulp.js seems to be a simple way to start, but the problem I am having is that I cannot get it to work. As there is no `npm install -g grunt2gulp`, I am somewhat unsure what I need to do to install the project globally and be able to access it.

The readme.md on the github repo doesn't specify how to install the project.

Comment: author of the library here, there's an issue created to set up the package.json and scripts properly so you can do grunt2gulp globally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the `grunt2gulp.js` file to the same directory as your `Gruntfile.js` file. Navigate to that path using terminal and paste this command:

```
node grunt2gulp.js Gruntfile.js > gulpfile.js
```

This will create a `gulpfile.js` file in the same directory.